# Weyl Groups/Borel

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, characteristic-classes

Could someone tell me where to find a proof of the following statement that I found in some notes about characteristic classes I was reading?

If $G$ is a compact connected Lie group with maximal
torus $T$ and Weyl group $W$ and if $H^∗(G)$ has no torsion for any prime $p$ that divides
the order of $W$, then
$H^∗
(BG) ∼= H^{∗}
(BT )^W .$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof can be found in Topology of Lie Groups I and II by Mimura and Toda, Ch VII Th 3.29. It can also be found in the works of Borel, in particular his springer notes. But the Mimura and Toda book gives the same proofs and Borel, just a little easier to read.